What happens after the API has responded in loopback 4
Hi All I have a question
this is my Jaeger trace

if you see 1) is my API which has responded in 7-8 sec but 2) the complete API took 12-13 sec
3) I want to know what happens in those remaining 5-6 sec
also what whatever is happening in between is it asynchronous?

After intensive debugging, I found out that the missing time is the time for stringifying the response. This is done by any server as only string can be transmitted over the network of course buffers and streams too but not objects or arrays
